# remove character from php key value array

Tags: php, arrays

[image]

This is the array i have right now. I want to remove the random open bracket in the [0] => ["A100" and also the random close bracket in [4] => "B11"] ....I ve tried using :

```
    foreach($list as $key=>$value)
{
    **//its suppose to be the same array that is $list not a new array $array**
    $list[$key]=str_replace("[","",$value);
}
```

$list being the array that contains the pictured elements. It doesnt seem to remove the brackets.. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE: **

Im getting the array from a localstorage sending it through post to another php where i catch the value and explode to a array called $list.

```
    $(function(){
    $('#fbtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'FactorAnalysis.php',
        type: 'POST', // GET or POST
        data: {data: localStorage.getItem('reportArray')}, // will be in $_POST on PHP side
        success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
            // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
            alert("Response is"+ data);
        },
        error: function() {
            // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
});
```

});

the localStorage outputted to a div shows me : 
[image]

so here im sending the data through a ajax call:

```
      $list = array();

       $list = explode(',',$_POST['data']);
```

^ then in another php (FactorAnalysis.php) i get the array and explode to array $list.

Comment: are you able to print $array[0]? is it like `["A100"` or `"[A100"`

Comment: when i print $list[0] it gives me ["A100" .. and when i print $list[1] it gives me "A101" which is what i want but the first and last element has square bracket .. which i want to remove

Comment: could you please write some more code? , is it coming from database or you are initializing it ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope you got a clearer understanding...

Comment: You are setting a new array in your loop. That means that every element in $list will contain the exact same value as before. The new string value is actually in the new array set in the foreach loop : $array. Are we clear on that?

Comment: No that is my mistake it should be $list not $array... i changed it and added a comment in the for loop. Sorry didnt see that mistake. The result however is the same.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $list = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

instead

```
$list = explode(',',$_POST['data']);
```